# C++ Beginner - Trouble using structs and constants!

Tags: c++, class, struct, global-variables

I am currently working on a simple Scrabble implementation for a college project.

I can't get a part of it to work, though!

Check this out:

My board.h:

http://pastebin.com/J9t8VvvB

The subroutine where the error lies:

```
//Following snippet contained in board.cpp
//I believe the function is self-explanatory...
//Pos is a struct containing a char, y, a int, x and an orientation, o, which is not   //used in this particular case
void Board::showBoard()
{
    Pos temp;
    temp.o = 0;

    for (temp.y = 'A'; temp.y < (65 + TOTAL_COLUMNS); ++temp.y)
    {
        for (temp.x = 1; temp-x < (1 + TOTAL_ROWS); ++temp.x)
        {
            cout << _matrix[temp].getContents();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The errors returned on compile time:

http://pastebin.com/bZv7fggq

How come the error states that I am trying to compare two Pos when I am comparing `char`s and `int`s?

I also really can't place these other errors...

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:

Since my whole project depends on Pos, I am going to try overloading the < operator for it... Can anyone give me a few tips on that? Keep in mind, I'm a beginner!

Comment: The code in those errors does not match what you pasted here.

Comment: `temp` is a struct, yet you are trying to pass it as an array index ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define TOTAL_ROWS 15;
#define TOTAL_COLUMNS 15;
```

Theses are preprocessor definitions, which must not end in a semicolon. The semicolon will become part of the substitution text, so the compiler sees something like `(65 + 15;)` which is clearly wrong.

In C++, it is better to use `const` variables instead of `#define`s. In this case, you could put the following in your `Board.cpp`:

```
const unsigned int TOTAL_ROWS = 15;
const unsigned int TOTAL_COLUMNS = 15;
```

You can then make them available through your header by putting these in `Board.h`:

```
extern const unsigned int TOTAL_ROWS;
extern const unsigned int TOTAL_COLUMNS;
```

Even cleaner is to declare them as class members. Put these in `Board.cpp`:

```
const unsigned int Board::TOTAL_ROWS = 15;
const unsigned int Board::TOTAL_COLUMNS = 15;
```

And in `Board.hpp`, *inside* the `public` section of the `class` definition:

```
static const unsigned int TOTAL_ROWS;
static const unsigned int TOTAL_COLUMNS;
```

They have to be `static` because they do not belong to any specific `Board` instance, but are rather properties of the class as a whole. You can then access them from outside the `Board` class by writing `Board::TOTAL_ROWS` etc.

---

The other problem here is that you are creating a `map<Pos, Cell>`. The `map` template requires that its key type (`Pos`) has a valid `<` operator defined on it; internally, the `map` sorts its elements using this operator, so it can do fast lookups. The error occurs only at the point where you try to look something up in the map; this is due to the way templates work, so don't break your head over it right now.

One solution is to overload this operator yourself to define an ordering on `Pos` objects. I would not recommend that to a beginner, because

- operator overloading is an advanced technique, and
- you have to be very careful to define consistent behaviour, or else the `map` stars misbehaving, and
- if you do this, you should also overload `>`, `<=`, and `>=`, `==` and `!=`.

That being said, here is the code. This assumes that two `Pos` objects with the same `x` and `y` values are considered equal; it does not look at the value of `o` (which is a weird thing to have in a "coordinate" type anyway, and I don't know what it's used for).

```
bool operator<(Pos const &l, Pos const &r) {
    if (l.y < r.y) return true;
    if (l.y > r.y) return false;
    if (l.x < r.x) return true;
    if (l.x > r.x) return false;
    return false;
}
```

The other (better) option is to abandon the `Pos` type completely, and represent your board as a two-dimensional array, or a `vector` of `vector`s. Its type would then be `vector<vector<Cell> >`. (Note the space between `> >`! Without it, this will be parsed as the right-shift operator `>>`!)

Comment: Thanks for answer + suggestion.
I'm sorry, what do you mean, "available through your header"?
--------
My whole project has its basis on the Pos type... How do I overload < for this particular type?

Comment: If you need to access the values of `TOTAL_ROWS` and `TOTAL_COLUMNS` from outside `Board.cpp`, say from `Main.cpp` or whatever, then you'd need those declarations. If you only use these constants inside `Board.cpp`, you do not have to declare them in the header.

Comment: Thanks, actually there's another class needing those constants.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the second part of your comment. I added some more on the operator overloading technique.